# How do you return a typed array in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, types, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I made a type in fortran called waveform and I made a function that reads through a file and makes an array of waveform types.

I want the function to return my waveform array, but I can't seem to figure out how to return the final array.

Below is my function

```
 !@param none                                                                                           
 !@return array of the configuration file                                                               

  function getWilloughby()


integer::it !iterator for do loop                                                                    
integer::size = 56661 !Expected dimension of waveforms array                                         

integer::io

real::x 
real::y 

real::lat

real::windspeed !Wind speed at that point                                                            
real::a !Willougby A parameter                                                                       

real::startX
real::startY

real::data(600)


type(waveform), allocatable ::waveforms(:) !An array to hold all waveforms                           
type(waveform), allocatable ::waveformsOut(:) !An array to hold all waveforms                        
allocate(waveforms(size))
allocate(waveformsOut(size))



open(1, file="Willoughby56_530-w.txt")

!Load configuration parameters                                                                       
read(1,*) windSteps, windStart, windInc, xSteps, ySteps, yInc, xInc, lat, xStart, yStart

write(*,*) "The wind parameters are" ,windStart, windSteps, windInc


write(*,*) "Loading Model Waveform data"

it = 1 !Iterator for do loop                                                                         

do
   it  = it + 1
   read(1,*, IOStat = io) x, y, windspeed, lat, a , startX, startY, data

   if(io > 0) then
      write(*,*) 'Check input. There was an error parsing the file'
      write(*,*) 'The error number is:' ,io
      exit
   else if (io < 0) then

      write(*,*) 'Finished reading the Willoughby configuration file'
      exit
   else
      !Read the Willoughby config file                                                               
      !Load each model waveform into a waveform type                                                 
      !Place the waveform into the waveforms array                                                   
      !write(*,*) "Waveform:", x, y, windspeed, lat, a, startX, startY, data                         
      waveforms(it)%x = x

      waveforms(it)%y = y
      waveforms(it)%windspeed = windspeed
      waveforms(it)%lat = lat
      waveforms(it)%startX = startX
      waveforms(it)%startY = startY
      waveforms(it)%data = data
      !write(*,*) waveforms(it)%data                                                                 
   end if
end do

write(*,*) waveforms


  end function getWilloughby
```

When I want to call the function from my main program like so, I get an error:

```
type(waveform), allocatable::modelwaveforms(:) 
modelwaveforms = getWilloughby()
```

Gfortran Compier error:

```
  modelwaveforms = getWilloughby()
               1
  Error: Can't convert REAL(4) to TYPE(waveform) at (1)
```

If I change the modelwaveforms(:) array into a REAL array like the error says, it compiles, but only gives me one value from the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining a type for getWilloughby so it is defaulting to real under implicit typing (use `implicit none` to turn off implicit typing so you'll get an error about not defining the return type).

To fix this you will need to define the return type, e.g.:

```
type(waveform), allocatable, dimension(:) :: getWilloughby ! return value
```

If you have a different variable that you want to be returned by the function, you can define the function as:

```
function getWilloughby() result(someOtherVariableName)
```

and make sure that `someOtherVariableName` is of type `type(waveform)`

and if the function is not in a module, you will need to define an explicit interface in the Fortran file that calls the function, e.g.

```
interface
  function getWilloughby()
    type(waveform), allocatable, dimension(:) :: getWilloughby
  end function
end interface
```

Comment: Thank so much for your help!!! So I changed my function declaration to type(waveform) function getWilloughby()
and it compiles, but I seg fault. Do I need to some how declare it as a type(waveform) array?

Comment: @EddieEMasseyIII please see my edit above.  I have changed the return type to an array (as I should have started with) and edited the interface accordingly.

Comment: Don't forget the assign the result in the function, I cannot find it anywhere in your code.

Comment: I got it! I didn't realize you that the return value of a function is the same as the name and that you can declare the type of the function within itself. Found a book, then I was able to fix my code from what you're saying. Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: @EddieEMasseyIII glad to hear it.  Also note that you can specify any variable as the return variable using `result()` as part of the function declaration, it doesn't have to be the same name as the function.